# How do I write more advanced functions/objects in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to write something that'll fit a linear regression on `x;y` as below.

```
fit: {
  coef: enlist[y] lsq flip[x];
  intercept: avg y;
  rSquared: sum raze[(intercept + (raze coef mmu flip[x]) - y) xexp 2];
  0"intercept";
  0"coef"; }
fit[x;y]
```

The issue I'm having is:

- How can I output `intercept`, `coef` and `rSquared` into some kind of single structured data format that I can use in my `predict` function (not shown). I tried to do

  `intercept`coef!(intercept coef)

but it wouldn't allow it owing to the resultant dictionary not being square.

What's the right way to handle this in KDB?

Comment: I think you are trying to use `0` to return a result here. This is not a valid operation in kdb+. Check this link: https://kdbfaq.com/how-do-i-set-the-return-value-of-a-function/

Comment: You also need a semi colon in your dictionary definition:  `intercept`coef!(intercept;coef)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a trivial example that may help.
Suppose I have function `f` that calculated three variables:

```
f:{[x] n1:x+10; n2:x+20; n3:x+30;}
```

I can have f output all three of these as a list:

```
f:{[x] n1:x+10; n2:x+20; n3:x+30;:(n1;n2;n3);}
```

If I then had a function `g` that summed three inputs I could feed the output from `f` into it like:

```
q)g:{[x;y;z] x+y+z};
q)g . f[10]
```

The `.` notation will apply the elements of it's right argument to it's left argument as if they were distinct variables.

You are, of course, free to leave `f[10]` as a list.
In this case your `g` would need a new definition:

```
q)g:{[l] l[0] + l[1] + l[2]}
q)g[f[10]]
```

The same could be accomplished with dictionaries but you would replace your numeric indices with symbolic ones.

```
q)f:{[x] n1:x+10; n2:x+20; n3:x+30;:`n1`n2`n3!(n1;n2;n3);}
q)g:{[d] d[`n1] + d[`n2] + d[`n3]}
q)g[f[10]]
```